# Where do stderr logs go, for gunicorn applications run by supervisor?

Tags: django, logging, gunicorn

I'm running Django under gunicorn on a DigitalOcean Debian server. This is the command I have used to start gunicorn:

```
exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers 3\
  --user=django_user--group=webapps\
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-
```

According to [the gunicorn docs on logging](https://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/develop/configure.html#logging), using `--log-file=-` means that all logging will have gone to stderr.

Given that I ran this `exec` command from inside a script that is called by supervisor, where will the stderr output have gone?

Answer (score 1):

This is something I did:

I created a file for supervisor: 'gunicorn.conf'

```
[program:gunicorn]
command = /opt/virtualenvs/myproject/bin/gunicorn_start
user = root
stdout = /path/to/file.log
stderr = /path/to/file.log
autostart = true
autorestart = true
```

And this is the file called above:

```
#!bin/bash
NAME="gunicorn"
DJANGODIR=/opt/virtualenvs/myproject/pysrc/myproject/myproject

# Enable virtualenv

cd $DJANGODIR
source ../../../bin/activate
export C_FORCE_ROOT="true"

# Execute SD
exec ...
```

As you can see there, I give a `stderr` and `stdout` path.

Comment: Thanks! This tells me how to redirect stderr, which is useful. But the question's about where the existing logs will have gone, do you know how I can find that out?